# Case insensitive routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I have a portion of a route Capitalized? For example I have a route `scim/v2/user` but I'd like it to be `scim/v2/User` (User capitalized). How can I achieve this while still using `resource`.

Routes file:

```
namespace :scim, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v2 do
    resource :user, only: [:create, :update, :show]
  end
end
```

When I run `$rake routes`, I get this:

```
                       scim_v2_user POST               /scim/v2/user(.:format)                                                           scim/v2/users#create {:format=>:json}
                                 GET                /scim/v2/user(.:format)                                                           scim/v2/users#show {:format=>:json}
                                 PATCH              /scim/v2/user(.:format)                                                           scim/v2/users#update {:format=>:json}
                                 PUT                /scim/v2/user(.:format)                                                           scim/v2/users#update {:format=>:json}
```

I'd like to either have the routes be `/scim/v2/User` or have them remain the same but have a way of mapping `/scim/v2/User` to `/scim/v2/user`.

Comment: You may want to consider not doing this, and create a separate redirect. If search bots like Google find URL's with different cases (e.g. where users put such a URL on other sites such as blogs and forums) but both result in a page (e.g. 200 OK) they may get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `resource` wants a direct mapping between the resource name and the controller, but you can simplify use an upper case resource name and manually specify the controller to get around this:

```
  namespace :scim, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v2 do
      resource :User, :controller => 'users', only: [:create, :update, :show]
    end
  end
```

Generates

```
      Prefix Verb  URI Pattern             Controller#Action
scim_v2_User GET   /scim/v2/User(.:format) scim/v2/users#show {:format=>:json}
             PATCH /scim/v2/User(.:format) scim/v2/users#update {:format=>:json}
             PUT   /scim/v2/User(.:format) scim/v2/users#update {:format=>:json}
             POST  /scim/v2/User(.:format) scim/v2/users#create {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: What's the difference between your solution and the one listed here: http://gehling.dk/2010/02/how-to-make-rails-routing-case-insensitive/.
Seems like yours is  better and doesn't require manipulating the middleware.

Comment: That solution involves using middleware to monkey with rails' routing. I always prefer to solve this within rails rather than layering another solution on top. You can definitely go this way if having to support both `User` and `user` is a constraint (you didn't specify in your question). I'd suggest going with something more proven like [rails downcaser](https://github.com/substancelab/route_downcaser) though

Comment: This will still be case sensitive, just with a different choice (e.g. `/scim/v1/User` rather than `/scim/v1/user`), but now `/scim/v1/user` wont work, neither will say `/scim/V1/User`, etc.. The middleware one linked converts the entire request path to lower case (so again not exactly case insensitive, but closer).

Comment: The fact that it's only one component is fine here, unless the OP has different constraints that I missed. Ideally there's no need to handle multiple cases (but I could see the need for a legacy API or similar use case). I don't understand how downcase is "not exactly case insensitive". If you want `scim/v2/User` and `scim/v2/user` to be treated in the same way that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by manually specifying the `path` and `controller`. I specified that `path` should be **Users** (capitalized). Below is code in my routes file:

```
  namespace :scim, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v2 do
      resources :user,
        path: "Users",
        controller: "users",
        only: [:create, :update, :index, :show]
    end
  end
```